# Can I add markers in After Effects without stopping the playback?

Tags: after-effects

Is there a way to add a marker without stopping the playback? I need to mark some specific times while the sequence is playing.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can add markers on the fly. Might be a job for scripting

Answer (score 2):

Use the keyboard shortcut to add a marker

> Windows: * (multiply) on numeric keypad
>   Mac OS: * (multiply) on numeric keypad or Control+8 on main keyboard

This works during preview and audio-only preview